# Python - Create a certain "number" of lists from user input "number"

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to Python and, programming as a whole, and not completely sure if this is possible but is there a way to create a "number" of lists based on an  inputted "number"?

Code should function as follows:

1. Ask user how many lists they want to create (Ex. user types 3)
2. Code will create three separate lists (Ex. list1 = [], list2 = [], list3 = [])

Note: I need lists specifically. No dictionaries, global, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to accomplish this is to simply store lists in a list of lists as such

```
num_lists = int(input('How many lists?'))
lists = [[] for i in range(num_lists)]
```

Then each list can be accessed by an index (for example `list1 = lists[0]`).

Comment: Wow! I didn't even think/know you could store lists in a list of lists. That definitely solves it. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution

```
num = int(input('How Many?: '))
all = {'list'+str(i+1):[] for i in range(num)}
print(all)
print(all['list1'])
```

sample output

```
How Many?: 3
{'list2': [], 'list3': [], 'list1': []}
[]
```

Comment: I guess I should've initially specified I didn't want to use dictionaries. Nonetheless, I see the code is essentially the same. Thanks for the future reference!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
lists=[[] for i in range(int(input('enter the number of list : ')))]
```

then you can access the list as index

first list

```
list1 =lists[0]
```

Comment: Oh you can further simplify the code. I SEE!!! Thanks Roushan45!!!